# update doc in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

update doc in mongoose.

```
Model.findOne({_id: '123'}, function (err, doc) {
  // some conditions 
  doc.body = 'body';
  doc.update(); //update the doc in db
});
```

The conditions are complex inline representation like `MyModel.update({ age: { $gt: 18 } }, { oldEnough: true }, fn);` as shown in [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update)

`doc.update();` does not work. How do i make the document update, most efficiently?

Comment: What do you expect `doc.update();` to do?  Wouldn't that be a no-op since you're not passing it any arguments?

Comment: i'm made changes in the prior code // some conditions          doc.body = 'body'; I want to run the command to let `doc` to reflect changes in the document in database.

Comment: Then you should call `doc.save()` instead.

Comment: that will create a new record. but i get your point. . . thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running your code with update, you have to use [save()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/). The reason is that your [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/) does absolutely nothing (you have not specified which documents you need to update and how to update it).

Save command will not create a new element, because you will not change the id of the element (if you are not doing this in `//some conditions code`). So it will just modify the element with that specific `_id`.